# Проблема подключения Unity ADS!

Tags: unity3d, ads

Всем Доброго времени суток..

Такая история: Есть проект к которому подключён Unity ADS, в проекте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую вызывается реклама.

И так проблема: при нажатии на кнопку, реклама то открывается, то нет. Бывает очень долго грузит рекламу, бывает игра тупо зависает, после чего приходиться перезапускаться проект.

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема ? Почему Unity ADS так некорректно работает, и вообще виноват ли в этом ADS, или мы что-то не так делаем ?

---

Button bt;

```
private void Start()
{

    Advertisement.AddListener(this);
    bt = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Button>();
}

private void Update()
{
    bt.interactable = Advertisement.IsReady("rewardedVideo");

}

public void OnClick()
{
    ADS.ShowVideo(View); 
    ShowOptions options = new ShowOptions();
    options.resultCallback = Result;
    Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideo",options);
}

void Result(ShowResult r)
{
    if(r == ShowResult.Finished)
    {
        View();
    }
}


void View()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Showed", 1);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score", Data.DataS.score);
    Time.timeScale = 1;
    Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
}

public void OnUnityAdsReady(string m)
{
    MailSender.SendMessage("OnUnityAdsReady: " + m);
}

public void OnUnityAdsDidError(string m)
{
    MailSender.SendMessage("OnUnityAdsDidError: " + m);
}

public void OnUnityAdsDidStart(string m)
{
    MailSender.SendMessage("OnUnityAdsDidStart: " + m);
}

public void OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string n, ShowResult r)
{

}
```

Comment: В редакторе у вас всё нормально? Unity Ads умеет показывать заглушки при тестировании. Если да - смотрите логи устройства через logcat - что там происходит, когда реклама вызывается

Comment: Простите, а где у Вас первичная инициализация UnityAds происходит? Добавте в метод `Start` инициализацию `Advertisement.Initialize(gameID, testMode)`